# How do I configure Celery to use separate BROKER_URLs for producing and consuming from the same broker?

Tags: python, celery, amqp

We have an application that uses a Celery instance in two ways: The instance's `.task` attribute is used as our task decorator, and when we invoke `celery worker`s, we pass the instance as the -A (--app) argument. This workflow uses the same Celery instance for both producing and consuming, and it has worked, but we are using the same Celery instance for both producers (the tasks) and consumers (the celery workers).

Now, we are considering using Bigwig RabbitMQ, which is an AMQP service provider, and they publish two *different* URLs, one optimized for message producers, the other optimized for message consumers.

What's the best way for us to modify our setup in order to take advantage of the separate broker endpoints? I'm assuming a single Celery instance can only use a single broker URL (via the BROKER_URL setting). Should we use two distinct Celery instances configured identically except for the BROKER_URL setting?

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be available in Celery 4.0: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/whatsnew-4.0.html#configure-broker-url-for-read-write-separately

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right one celery instance can use only one broker URL. As you said the only way is to use 2 workers with just different BROKER_URL one for consuming and one for producing.

Technically is trivial, you can take advantage of this (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.config_from_object) but off course you will have two workers running but I don't think that this introduces any problem.

There is also another option explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824639/celery-configure-separate-connection-for-producer-and-consumer) , but I would avoid it.